# Round Python list with unique values

Tags: python, rounding

I want to "round" an ordered list of numeric values, that can be in the form of (positive / negative) floats or integers. I do not want identical values within the output, unless the incoming values themselves were identical. I would ideally like rounding to the nearest 5 or 10, performed at the highest level of magnitude possible, and descending down until there is a non-match between adjacent values.

The following are some examples of what I'm looking for:

`[-0.1, 0.21, 0.29, 4435.0, 9157, 9858.0, 10758.0, 11490.0, 12111.9]`

Results in:

`[-0.1, 0.0, 0.25, 5000.0, 9000.0, 10000.0, 11000.0, 11500.0, 12000.0]`

Here's what I have so far:

```
def rounder(n, base=1):
    base = base * (10 ** (len(str(abs(n))) - len(str(abs(n)))))
    return base * round(float(n)/base)

for i in range(len(inp_values)-1):
    while True:
        a = rounder(inp_values[i], 10**((len(str(abs(int(inp_values[i])))))-(i+1)) / 2)
        b = rounder(inp_values[i+1], 10**((len(str(abs(int(inp_values[i+1])))))-(i+1)) / 2)
        print a, b
        if a < b:
            break
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain `0.21 --> 0.0`?

Comment: If it went to `0.25`, then the result would be identical to the one right of it.

Comment: Is there a real-world use case for this?

Comment: Yes, the rounded numbers are for formatting. I'm trying to have well-formatted quantile breaks within the ArcGIS legend. This is part of a project I'm working on to create dynamic symbology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you keep a dictionary of numbers you rounded (before round = key, after round = value), and write a for loop that rounds using less precision if the rounded value would collide in the dictionary? For example:

```
from math import log10, floor

def roundSD(x, sd):
    "Returns x rounded to sd significant places."
    return round(x, -int(floor(log10(abs(x)))) + sd - 1)

def round5(x, sd):
    "Returns x rounded to sd significant places, ending in 5 and 0."
    return round(x * 2, -int(floor(log10(abs(x)))) + sd - 1) / 2




inputData = [-0.1, 0.21, 0.29, 4435.0, 9157, 9858.0, 10758.0, 11490.0, 12111.9]
roundedDict = {}
roundedData = []

for input in inputData:
    if input in roundedDict:
        # The input is already calculated.
        roundedData.append(roundedDict[input])
        continue

    # Now we attempt to round it
    success = False
    places = 1
    while not success:
        rounded = roundSD(input, places)
        if rounded in roundedDict.values():
            # The value already appeared! We use better precision
            places += 1
        else:
            # We rounded to the correct precision!
            roundedDict[input] = rounded
            roundedData.append(rounded)
            success = True
```

This will guarantee if two numbers are the same, they will give identical rounded output. If two numbers are different, they will never give identical outputs.

A run from above gives:

`[-0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 4000.0, 9000.0, 10000.0, 11000.0, 11500.0, 12000.0]`

Feel free to change the round function to your own to incorporate round to 5 & 10 only.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! I'm not quite sure what the rationale was for down voting this answer. If possible, could you explain how I might round to 5s and 10s only?

Comment: Well, I think the current answer looks pretty neat, but if you insist, check out the alternative round function I've added above. Note that 4435 still won't round to 5000 though, because 4500 is closer.